# How can I set the Bold typeface for System.Windows.Fontstyle?

Tags: c#, .net

There are only `Italic`, `Normal`, `Oblique`. But I need to set my `FontStyle` Bold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Bold` isn't a FontStyle. It is a font weight. See [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontweight.aspx) and [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontweights.aspx) links.

For example:

```
control.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
```

**`Update`**: Of course this answer is for XAML based frameworks (WPF, Silverlight, WinPhone, WinRT). In other frameworks bold can be style or something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
myTextBox.Font =
  new Font(myTextBox.Font, outputTextBox.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
```